MAMP Pro - restore Hosts configurations
When you create a new Virtual Host in MAMP PRO, where on the MAMP file system is this configuration stored?
I had to reinstall MAMp Pro (Mac) so I created a backup of both
Applications/MAMP
Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO
Upon reinstalling MAMP PRO, I could just copy/paste my database directories stored in
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
This successfully restored my databases
What I can't find is where my Hosts Virtual configs are stored which might enable me to copy back a file etc to see them again and appear in the Hosts panel of MAMP Pro.

